# What does "variable=${2%?}$i" mean in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Can anyone explain the following bash snippet?

```
for i in $(seq 1 1 10)
do
   VAR=${2%?}$i
   break;
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It removes the trailing character from `$2` (second positional parameter) and concatenates that value with `$i`

example:

```
$ v1="myvalue1x"
$ v2="myvalue2"
$ combined="${v1%?}$v2"
$ echo $combined
myvalue1myvalue2
```

For more info how the substitution works you can check the `Parameter Expansion` section of the bash manual

Comment: The question mark isn't literal, it's a special character in shell patterns and stands for "any character". `${v%?}` removes the last character from `v`, no matter what it is.

Comment: Perhaps an example that used a non-`?` character in `v1` would further clarify?

Comment: addressed both comments

Answer (score 0):

See the bash man page, section *parameter expansion*:

```
   ${parameter%word}
   ${parameter%%word}
          Remove  matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a
          pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the  pattern  matches  a
          trailing  portion  of  the  expanded  value  of parameter, then the
          result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the
          shortest  matching pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest matching
          pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter is  @  or  *,  the
          pattern  removal  operation is applied to each positional parameter
          in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter  is
          an  array  variable  subscripted  with  @ or *, the pattern removal
          operation is applied to each member of the array in turn,  and  the
          expansion is the resultant list.
```

Since **?** matches a single character, the trailing character is removed from the second argument of the script.